# Animator controller does not transitioning even though parameter condition is met

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to transition from idle to attack when a boolean parameter is true.
my code does set the boolean parameter and I can see that it's set to true in the animator. but transition doesn't happen. while in playing mode once I change anything in the animator, suddenly transition works fine.
this is my code.

```
public class Wraith : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] GameObject projectile;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 projectilePosition;

    AttackerSpawner myLaneSpawner;
    Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        SetLaneSpawner();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (HasAttakerInLane())
        {
            animator.SetBool("shouldAttack", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("shouldAttack", false);
        }

    }
```

and this is my animator controller.
[Animator controller schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ntz.png)

and
[transition settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7arSp.png)

**Update**
I get rid off exit time so only bool condition  is required for transition   and instead used the code below to make sure transition happens at a given time after idle animation played. now transition works fine.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (HasAttackerInLane() && animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime >= 1.5f)
        {
            animator.SetBool("shouldAttack", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("shouldAttack", false);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Several moments:

- you have `ExitTime` enabled in your transition. It means that transition cannot start immediately
- you are setting `bool` flag every update (many times per second), so it can easily become `false` right after was set to `true`

I suspect that you have the combo of these moments. Your flag becomes false earlier than your transition can begin.

Comment: hi. thanks. should have mentioned that I don't want the animation to start immediately that's why I have the exit time. the problem is transition dose not happen even after exit time has passed. and I know for a fact that bool condition stay true and don't change to false for a good couple of seconds in the game. although it seems that the problem is with the exit time. as I understood from docs exit time acts like a bool that becomes true for a single frame and becomes false in the next frame so maybe somehow tow conditions for transition to happen doesn't meet at a single frame